# Unable to recieve id and consume it using useParams. Page showing blank in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, use-state

I have two pages one with a list of products which are rendering fine but when i click any of them it is taking me to route with id but with blank page. My product Details page is not able to consume the id and render the items. There is something wrong but I am not able to find it. How do i solve this?

```
App.js
<Routes>
 <Route path="/" element={<Products />}></Route>
 <Route path="/:id" element={<ProductDetails />}></Route> 
</Routes>

Products Page
{items && items.map(({ id, name,price, desc, small, large }) => (
                <Grid item xs={6} xs={12} sm={6} md={3} >
                  <Link to={`/${id}`}>
                  <Card key={id}>
                    <div>
                      <h2>{name}</h2>
                      <h3>Rs {price}</h3>
                    </div>
                  </Card>
                  </Link>
                </Grid>
              ))}


Product Details Page
function ProductDetail() {
    const [singleProduct, setSingleProduct] = useState({})
    const { id } = useParams()
    const findProduct = () => {
      setSingleProduct(data.find((product) => product.id === id))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        findProduct()
    }, [id])

    
    return (
        <section>
        <img src={singleProduct.large} alt="" />
        <h1>
          {singleProduct.name}
        </h1>
        </section>
)}
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code you have an issue working with in your question. Can we see how the routes are declared? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also, there's no need really to store the found product locally in state, just render directly from the found product object.

Comment: @DrewReese I have added  them now.

Comment: Are you using `react-router-dom`? If you so, please use the `useNavigation` hook that is included in the new version of the `react-router-dom`. based on the date of the question you have posted I imagine you are using `react-router-dom-v6` unless you are using `v5` please check out [this link](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-string) from the documentation Itself

Comment: @EmadBaqeri The `useNavigate` hook serves an *entirely* different purpose than the `Link` component. The difference is imperative vs declarative navigation. The `Link` component generally functions the same between `RRDv5` and `v6`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the routes look correct and I see no reason why the `id` param *wouldn't* defined I believe this is a type-mismatch issue where the route param is a string type and the `product.id` is not a string type.

Use a type-safe comparison when searching the `data` by converting the `product.id` to a string.

Example:

```
const { id } = useParams();

const findProduct = () => {
  setSingleProduct(data.find((product) => String(product.id) === id))
}
```

And as I pointed out in a comment, there's no need to use any local state, just find the data and render directly.

Example:

```
function ProductDetail() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const singleProduct = data.find((product) => String(product.id) === id)) || {};

  return (
    <section>
      <img src={singleProduct.large} alt="" />
      <h1>{singleProduct.name}</h1>
    </section>
  );
}
```