# React Links in React-Router-Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am not sure why my images are not clickable.  In HomeScreen when clicking on the image,  <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}><Card.Img src={product.image} /> its supposed to be pulling productscreen 1 product details but it doesn't do anything.  react-router-dom version 6.3

App.js

```
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Routes,  Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen';


function App() {
  return (
  <Router>
    <Header />
    <main className="py-3">
      <Container>
      <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} exact />
            <Route path="/products/:id" element={<ProductScreen />} />
          </Routes>
      <HomeScreen/>
       </Container>
     </main>
     <Footer/>
     </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

HomeScreen.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap'
import products from '../products'
import Product from '../components/Product'

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Latest Products</h1>
    <Row>
        {products.map(product =>(
            <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
            <Product product={product} />
            </Col>
        ))}
    </Row>
    
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Product.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Rating from './Rating'

function Product({product}) {
  return (
    <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded shadow-sm">
      
      <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
        <Card.Img src={product.image} />
      </Link>

      <Card.Body>
      
      <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
        <Card.Title as="div" className="text-center">
            <strong>{product.name}</strong>
        </Card.Title>
      </Link>

      <Card.Text as="div" >
        <div className="my-3 text-center">
          <Rating value={product.rating} text={`(${product.numReviews})`} color={'#f8e825'}/>
        </div>
      </Card.Text>

      <Card.Text as="h4" className="text-center">
        ${product.price}
      </Card.Text>
      </Card.Body>

    </Card>
  )
}

export default Product
```

ProductScreen.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Button, Card} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import products from '../products'


function ProductScreen() {
    const match = useParams();
    const product = products.find((p) => p._id == match.id)
  return (
    <div>
      {product.name}
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductScreen
```

products.js

```
const products = [
  {
    '_id': '1',
    'name': 'Airpods Wireless Bluetooth Headphones',
    'image': '/images/airpods.jpg',
    'description':
      'Bluetooth technology lets you connect it with compatible devices wirelessly High-quality AAC audio offers immersive listening experience Built-in microphone allows you to take calls while working',
    'brand': 'Apple',
    'category': 'Electronics',
    'price': 89.99,
    'countInStock': 10,
    'rating': 4.5,
    'numReviews': 12,
  },
  {
    '_id': '2',
    'name': 'iPhone 11 Pro 256GB Memory',
    'image': '/images/phone.jpg',
    'description':
      'Introducing the iPhone 11 Pro. A transformative triple-camera system that adds tons of capability without complexity. An unprecedented leap in battery life',
    'brand': 'Apple',
    'category': 'Electronics',
    'price': 599.99,
    'countInStock': 7,
    'rating': 4.0,
    'numReviews': 8,
  },
  {
    '_id': '3',
    'name': 'Cannon EOS 80D DSLR Camera',
    'image': '/images/camera.jpg',
    'description':
      'Characterized by versatile imaging specs, the Canon EOS 80D further clarifies itself using a pair of robust focusing systems and an intuitive design',
    'brand': 'Cannon',
    'category': 'Electronics',
    'price': 929.99,
    'countInStock': 5,
    'rating': 3,
    'numReviews': 12,
  },
  {
    '_id': '4',
    'name': 'Sony Playstation 4 Pro White Version',
    'image': '/images/playstation.jpg',
    'description':
      'The ultimate home entertainment center starts with PlayStation. Whether you are into gaming, HD movies, television, music',
    'brand': 'Sony',
    'category': 'Electronics',
    'price': 399.99,
    'countInStock': 11,
    'rating': 5,
    'numReviews': 12,
  },
  {
    '_id': '5',
    'name': 'Logitech G-Series Gaming Mouse',
    'image': '/images/mouse.jpg',
    'description':
      'Get a better handle on your games with this Logitech LIGHTSYNC gaming mouse. The six programmable buttons allow customization for a smooth playing experience',
    'brand': 'Logitech',
    'category': 'Electronics',
    'price': 49.99,
    'countInStock': 7,
    'rating': 3.5,
    'numReviews': 10,
  },
  {
    '_id': '6',
    'name': 'Amazon Echo Dot 3rd Generation',
    'image': '/images/alexa.jpg',
    'description':
      'Meet Echo Dot - Our most popular smart speaker with a fabric design. It is our most compact smart speaker that fits perfectly into small space',
    'brand': 'Amazon',
    'category': 'Electronics',
    'price': 29.99,
    'countInStock': 0,
    'rating': 4,
    'numReviews': 12,
  },
]


export default products
```

Comment: You click on a link and *absolutely* nothing happens? Or you click on a link and the URL changes and the expected content isn't rendered? Can you clarify the issue and expected vs observed behavior? Can you include the `products` data you are using in your post? Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71849445/8690857

Comment: Thank you for asking that.  Yes the URL changes but isn't rendering.  Its going from localhost:3000 to localhost:3000/product/1 or whatever the id is but the render stays the same.

Comment: I added product.js to the original code above

Comment: Thanks. Does that link answer your question? Can we see the data that you are trying to match against?

Comment: Ah, you know what, it's a silly typo. You render a route on path `"/products/:id"` but link to a `"/product/${product._id}"`. The link target path is missing an `"s"`, or the route path has an additional `"s"`. Fix one or the other so route path and link target are in agreement.

Comment: I removed the 2 from products and now  it renders the product name but on the HomeScreen and not a new ProductDetail screen <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductScreen />} />

Comment: The product name appears to render as I'd expect here in this [codesandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-links-in-react-router-dom-lccgmo) that I've copy/pasted your code into. Are there any errors on your end with your code? What is the value of `product` in `ProductScreen` in your code?

Comment: When I click on a product name or image, the url changes but the page does not.  It just renders the name of the product above latest products  but has all the products below not the single product as it should

Comment: You are rendering `HomeScreen` component twice. Once conditionally on a route, and once unconditionally outside the `Routes` component. Note that in the sandbox I linked I'd commented out that line of code so the component wasn't a duplicate render.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you so much.  I thought I took it out.  That worked.  Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

I read your answer. When you click the product, site doesn't redirect clicked product page. Because Link component in sub-div tag or component doesn't run.

You can modify your code as my following code.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import products from '../products'
import Product from '../components/Product'

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Latest Products</h1>
    <Row>
        {products.map(product =>(
            <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
              <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                <Product product={product} />
              </Col>
            </Link>
        ))}
    </Row>
    
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Otherwise, you can modify in this way.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import products from '../products'
import Product from '../components/Product'

function HomeScreen() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleChangePage = (id) => {
    navigate(`/product/${id}`);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Latest Products</h1>
    <Row>
        {products.map(product =>(
            <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3} onClick={() => handleChangePage(product._id)}>
              <Product product={product} />
            </Col>
        ))}
    </Row>
    
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```